# How can i add validation on my file uploader?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have this file uploader that i made (it works and it uploads files) but i want to make validation so only pictures / gifs can be uploaded, i just dont know how.

Can someone help me please? I work in razor pages asp.net core.

Here is the code:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
   private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment;
   private readonly IChampData champData;
   private readonly IHtmlHelper htmlHelper;

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

   [BindProperty]
   public Champion Champion { get; set; }

   [BindProperty]
   public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }

   public IActionResult OnPost()
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           if (Champion.Id == 0 && Photo != null)
           {                    
               Champion.LinkUrl = ProcessUploadedFile();
               Champion = champData.Create(Champion);
           }

           champData.Commit();
           return RedirectToPage("./List", new { championId = Champion.Id });
       }
       Roles = htmlHelper.GetEnumSelectList<Role>();
       return Page();
   }

   private string ProcessUploadedFile()
   {
       string uniqueFileName = null;
       if (Photo != null)
       {
           string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Photos");
           uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Photo.FileName;
           string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
           using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
           {
               Photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
           }
       }
       return uniqueFileName;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint: You can check the file extension and add a condition for the file type. Once you code this, and it does not work, then ask with code, where you are wrong. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: just checking the extension is bad. you can call a .docx like a.png and manually open it with MS Word and you will not have any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this function on button click so validate it in client-side :

```
 var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png"];
        function ValidatePhoto(oInput) {
            if (oInput.type == "file") {
                var sFileName = oInput.value;
                if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                    var blnValid = false;
                    for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                        var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                        if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                            $('#invalidImg').html("");
                            blnValid = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!blnValid) {
                        $('#invalidImg').html("<p class='text-danger'>Sorry, " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", ") + "</p>");
                        oInput.value = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: I think im doing something wrong, i cant seem to make it work, this is the html where i click to upload a file :  " <label asp-for="Photo" class="col-sm-1"></label> <div class="form-group col-sm-4"> <div class="custom-file"> <input class="custom-file-input form-control" asp-for="Photo" /> <label class="custom-file-label" onclick="ValidatePhoto()">Click Here to insert photo</label> </div> </div>"

i added your code bellow this ^ in a <script>

Comment: <input type="file" class="upload" onchange="return ValidatePhoto(this);" name="logo" />   I am using this and it is validated as you chose a file or drop it . It is not working for you because you are not passing file parameter. As soon as you modify so the parameter is passed correctly it works very good

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with asp but 
System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename) should do the trick.

MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping produces these results:

```
file.jpg: image/jpeg
file.gif: image/gif
file.jpeg: image/jpeg
file.png: image/png
file.bmp: image/bmp
file.tiff: image/tiff
```

With that you are able to check for almost every image file. If you have other file types you have to check the file header yourself.